# Remix IDE: Cannot create an account: Not running in personal mode

Tags: remix, metamask, ide

I'm trying to create an account from Remix IDE on remix.ethereum.org. When I try to create an account it gives me an error

Cannot create an account: Not running in personal mode

What does this mean? How to correct this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**RESOLVED**:

Personal mode can be updated from the **settings** tab in the remix IDE.

According to this github link: https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/705

> there's a little explanation in the settings tab (allow to fille the
>   passphrase from remix and not from the node)